# SQL two tables distinct counts with join

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange

I have two tables.

Table 1 contains orders and customer codes.
Table 2 contains orders with issue codes.

I need to be able to return distinct order count by customer from table 1 along with a distinct count by customer of orders with issuecode of 'F' from table 2.  Then the final field will be a ratio of the two.  Issue count / Order count.  I'm using AS400/DB2 SQL.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

`Customer  ORcnt  IScnt  IssueRatio
cust1      450     37      0.082
cust2      255     12      0.047
cust3      1024    236     0.230
cust4      450     37      0.082`

Comment: It's hard for anybody to help you without knowing the structure of your tables with sample data that relates to your desired results.   Also people will be more inclined to help if you show the code you've tried so far and why it didn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use an `outer join` to your issues table and `count` with `distinct`.  Something like this depending on your table definitions:

```
select o.customercode, 
       count(distinct o.orderid), 
       count(distinct i.orderid), 
       count(distinct i.orderid)/count(distinct o.orderid) ratio
from table1 o
      left join table2 i on o.orderid = i.orderid and i.issuecode = 'F'
group by o.customercode
```

Some databases would need to convert the ratio to a decimal -- I'm not sure about `db2`.  If needed, one way is to multiply the result by 1.0:

`1.0*count(distinct i.orderid)/count(distinct o.orderid)`

Also, you may not need the `distinct` with the `count` -- depends on your data...

Comment: Thank you so much sir, you just got me out of quite the bind!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this is a `join` query along with conditional aggregation:

```
select t1.customer, count(*) as ordercnt,
       sum(case when issuecode = 'F' then 1 else 0 end) as issuecnt,
       avg(case when issuecode = 'F' then 1.0 else 0 end) as issuep
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.orderid = t2.orderid
group by t1.customer;
```

Comment: What does the `1.9` do for you here?  And I think you'll need your `sum(...)/count(*)` to get the ratio unless I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: That should be `1.0` and it is easier to use `avg()` than to do the division.

Comment: I think both are valid solutions.  I was missing the 1.0 part in my script.  Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing this w/ a few subqueries to make it more readable in terms of the description of the problem you presented. sgeddes' solution probably also works (and might perform better) depending on the precise structure of your data.

```
SELECT t.customer,
       count(t.orderID_All),
       count(t.orderID_F),
       count(t.orderID_F)/count(t.orderID_All)
FROM
  (SELECT orders.customer,
          orders.orderID AS orderID_All,
          issues.orderID AS orderID_F /*assuming primary/unique key is customer-orderID*/
   FROM table1 orders
   LEFT OUTER JOIN /*you want *all* orders on the left and just orders w/ 'F' on the right*/
     (SELECT DISTINCT orderID
      FROM table2
      WHERE issuecode = 'F') issues ON orders.orderID = issues.orderID) t
GROUP BY t.customer;
```